# In new Gmail, how can I prevent label list from autocollapsing?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail's new UI, is there a way to prevent the "**label list**", or whatever you call it, from automatically collapsing whenever I'm not hovering over it with mouse/trackpad? This is what I mean (here shown collapsed):

[image]

I find it annoying to have to hover over a quite small area, in this case the "Starred" text, to be able to see & click on my labels and stuff like Sent Mail, Drafts, and All Mail.

I looked around in Settings, but didn't find anything that affects this. (In case this is some kind of bug, I'm using Chrome on a Mac.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hover over the line under **Starred**. Upon hover, three little dots will appear (see screenshot below). Click on it/them and then drag downwards.

Normal state:                            Hover state:
[image]       [image]

Comment: Thanks, the solution was closer than I thought! I guess I didn't notice the little dots or expect that part of the UI to be so "desktop-like".

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/21980/117564) will not work if you have the Display mode set to Touch Enabled, which may be the case if you have a touch screen display or a hybrid/convertible machine.  Change it to one of the other settings and sanity will be restored.

[image: Touch Enabled Settings]

Answer (score -1):

Try this...
Select "show" or "hide"
See what will happen..
[image]